# How to simplify the below inner JOIN SQL query

Tags: sql, fetch, inner-join, offset

I am getting records from different tables and concatenating the values like this so that I can display Flight1, Flight2, Flight3, and Flight4...... as columns.
Since I am using the same conditions, Is there any way to simplify this query?

```
SELECT b.BookingID

,(SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT(il.CCode,il.FlightNumber,';',dc.[Name])
        FROM ILeg il
        INNER JOIN PLeg pjl ON pjl.InventoryLegID = il.InventoryLegID
             INNER JOIN PSegment pjs ON pjs.SegmentID = pjl.SegmentID
             INNER JOIN BPassenger bp ON bp.PassengerID = pjs.PassengerID
             INNER JOIN City dc ON dc.CityCode = il.DepartureStation
             INNER JOIN City ac ON ac.CityCode = il.ArrivalStation
             WHERE bp.BookingID =  b.BookingID AND il.CarrierCode = '12T'
             ORDER BY il.STD
             ) AS Flight1

,(SELECT CONCAT((il.CCode,il.FlightNumber,';',dc.[Name]))
        FROM ILeg il
        INNER JOIN PLeg pjl ON pjl.InventoryLegID = il.InventoryLegID
             INNER JOIN PSegment pjs ON pjs.SegmentID = pjl.SegmentID
             INNER JOIN BPassenger bp ON bp.PassengerID = pjs.PassengerID
             INNER JOIN City dc ON dc.CityCode = il.DepartureStation
             INNER JOIN City ac ON ac.CityCode = il.ArrivalStation
             WHERE bp.BookingID =  b.BookingID AND il.CarrierCode = '12T'
             ORDER BY il.STD
             OFFSET 1 ROWS
        FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) AS Flight2

,(SELECT CONCAT((il.CCode,il.FlightNumber,';',dc.[Name]))
        FROM ILeg il
        INNER JOIN PLeg pjl ON pjl.InventoryLegID = il.InventoryLegID
             INNER JOIN PSegment pjs ON pjs.SegmentID = pjl.SegmentID
             INNER JOIN BPassenger bp ON bp.PassengerID = pjs.PassengerID
             INNER JOIN City dc ON dc.CityCode = il.DepartureStation
             INNER JOIN City ac ON ac.CityCode = il.ArrivalStation
             WHERE bp.BookingID =  b.BookingID AND il.CarrierCode = '12T'
             ORDER BY il.STD
             OFFSET 2 ROWS
        FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) AS Flight3

FROM Booking b
WHERE b.RecordLocator='1234'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CTE on top and the main query **might** look as below.

```
;with CTE as 
(SELECT CONCAT((il.CCode,il.FlightNumber,';',dc.[Name])) as DisplayName
        FROM ILeg il
        INNER JOIN PLeg pjl ON pjl.InventoryLegID = il.InventoryLegID
             INNER JOIN PSegment pjs ON pjs.SegmentID = pjl.SegmentID
             INNER JOIN BPassenger bp ON bp.PassengerID = pjs.PassengerID
             INNER JOIN City dc ON dc.CityCode = il.DepartureStation
             INNER JOIN City ac ON ac.CityCode = il.ArrivalStation
             WHERE bp.BookingID =  b.BookingID AND il.CarrierCode = '12T'
             ORDER BY il.STD),
SELECT b.BookingID
,(SELECT TOP 1 * from CTE) AS Flight1
,(SELECT TOP 1 * from CTE OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) AS Flight2
,(SELECT TOP 1 * from CTE OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) AS Flight3
FROM Booking b
WHERE b.RecordLocator='1234'
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error "multi-part identifier "b.BookingID" could not be bound" near WHERE bp.BookingID =  b.BookingID.
Do you know the reason?